# How to have a dynamic page name with php

Tags: php, url

I have a question, I developed an account dashboard that is accessible from a URL like `http://example.com/dashboard`. The question is: how can I dynamically change the page url, to do something like `http://example.com/$username`, so for example if an user register to my site, with the username "abcd", he will display `/abcd` instead of `/dashboard`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use .htaccess to redirect all your request to index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Then in your index.php, need to parse the URL ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) and decide what to display depending on the URL parameter.